# jQuery http digest authentication cross domain

Tags: jquery, authentication, google-chrome-extension, digest-authentication

I am developing a Chrome Extension that loads an external JS, that points to some REST API.

These APIs needs HTTP (digest) authentication. How do I perform cross domain jQuery http digest authentication?

I would like not to implement it into the chrome extension, but in the externally loaded JS (so that I can update the external js to update all of my clients)

Comment: Why wouldn't you to able to do that?

Comment: I did that for the chrome extension, however it looks to me impossible or very difficult to replicate that in the external js. I dont want you to write the code, I would like to have strategy suggestions.